# Prove that $10 \times n^2 > n!$ is false for all n in the natural numbers

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I know this statement can be easily disproven by using a counter example (like n = 6) but I was wondering if there was a more rigorous proof for this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *"more rigorous proof for this problem"*? You have given a counter example of the statement. I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Prove that $10n^2 \le n!$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: When $n=3$, $10*3^2$ is *greater* than $3!$. However, when $n = 6$, $10*6^2$ is *smaller* than $6!$. Therefore, you cannot show that one is greater than the other for all the natural numbers.

Comment: @stevengregory I'd like to see you prove that one.

Comment: $n=0$ is the smallest counter example

Comment: @5xum - I said what he needed to prove. He didn't ask if it was possible.

Comment: Well that's easy to prove that the factorial is getting bigger at some point ( n>5) than the polynomial...I upvoted since the question is reallly interesting so + 1

Comment: @stevengregory But that's not what he needs to prove.

Comment: @5xum He asked: how do I prove $\forall n\in \mathbb N,\neg(\neg P(n))$? That is equivalent to $\forall n\in \mathbb N,P(n)$. If he had asked: is $\forall n\in \mathbb N,\neg(\neg P(n))$ true, then all he would have to do is show $\exists n\in \mathbb N,\neg P(n)$.

Comment: Arjun, please make use of the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem you want help with.  Here, with the title only serving to give what seems to be an overly terse presentation of the problem, the statement is ambiguous.  **Is** it a simple matter of showing the inequality **fails** for *some* natural number $n$, or rather to show it **fails** for *all* natural numbers $n$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by *rigorously*.

---

If the statement is:

$$\forall x\in X: P(x)$$

(where $P(x)$ is some statement about the element $x$), then the negation of this statement is

$$\exists x\in X: \neg P(x).$$

A proof of any statement that begins with $\exists$ can be done **rigorously** by finding one such $x$ that satisfies the statement following the quantifier.

This means that if $\neg P(x_0)$ is true for some $x_0\in X$, then this very fact **proves** that $$\exists x\in X: \neg P(x)$$ is a true statement, and since this is a strue statement, its negation is a false statement.

---

In your case, the original statement is

$$\forall n\in\mathbb N: 10n^2>n!$$

and its negation is

$$\exists n\in\mathbb N: 10n^2\leq n!.$$

Setting $n_0=6$ means that the statement $$10n_0^2 \leq n!$$ is **true**, meaning that the statement

$$\exists n\in\mathbb N: 10n^2\leq n!$$

is also true, and this means that the original statement is false.

---

Every logical step I explained is correct, so I would call this proof *rigorous*.

Answer (score 1):

For $ n \geq 6 $ it's possible to prove that the statement is false

$10 n^² \leq n!$
$10 n^² - n! \leq 0$
$ n(10n- (n-1)!) \leq 0$
$ (10n- (n-1)!) \leq 0$  since n is natural

it's easy to prove that $(n-2)(n-1) \geq n $ for $n\geq 4$

And that 1.2.3.4 $\geq 10=1.2.5$
.....you can show then that n must be $\geq 6$

So for $ n \geq 6 $ , $n! \geq 10 n^2 $

Answer (score 1):

It's important to distinguish between the following:

- $10n^2>n!$ is false for all $n\in\mathbb N$ (what you wrote) and
- The statement "$10n^2>n!$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$" is false

The first version would be equivalent to "$10n^2\leq n!$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$", and you would need to prove this for every $n$. But you can't, because it isn't true for all $n$, as Toby Mak points out. (It's true for all $n\geq 6$, and you could prove this e.g. by induction.)

For the second version, a counterexample is enough, as 5xum says.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: 
For every $6 \leq n \in \mathbb{N}$ , 
we have $10 \times n^2 < n!$ .

**Proof by induction**: 
The claime is true for $n=6$ . 
$ \ \ \ \ \ \checkmark \checkmark \checkmark$

Suppose that the assertion holds for $k=n$; 
i.e. $\color{Blue}{10 \times n^2 < n!}$ ,

on the other hand we know that : $ 22 < n! $;
also we know that $ 10 < 2n$ , which implies $20n+10 < 22n$;
so we can conclude that:

$$ 
22 < n! 
\Longrightarrow 
22  n < n! \cdot n 
\Longrightarrow 
20n+10 < n! \cdot n 
\Longrightarrow 
\color{Red}{10 \times (2n+1) < n! \cdot n} 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
10 \times (n+1)^2 = 
\color{blue}{ 10 \times n^2} + 
\color{Red}{10 \times (2n+1)} 
< 
\color{Blue}{n!} + 
\color{Red}{n! \cdot n} = 
n!(1+n) = 
(n+1)! 
\ \ 
; 
$$ 
which implise the claime for $k=n+1$ .